# How to make a CHECK constraint that allow user to only input DateTime from today and onwards?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, check-constraints

As with the title, I'm trying to solve my **CHECK constraint where user are only able to enter Date and Time from today and onward**.

Here is the SQL developer version that I'm using now (I queried the version):

- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

- PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production

What I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE job_assignment
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_start_date CHECK ( start_date >=
    SYSDATE()
);
```

but this gave me an error, ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

And I have also come across this, 

Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following constructs:

- Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions
- Calls to the functions that are not deterministic (CURRENT_DATE,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DBTIMEZONE,
    LOCALTIMESTAMP, SESSIONTIMEZONE,
    **SYSDATE**, SYSTIMESTAMP, UID, USER, and USERENV)

Need help pls.

Comment: A check constraint is firing on every update. Even if this would work, it means that your row is locked for everything but deletions as soon as start_date is in the pas. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, my start_date will not be changed (ever) after it has been input into the table (given that it pass the CHECK constraint). It just need to check upon input that the user has enter a date and time from today or onward. Row will not change as this table is kept for record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a trigger, e.g.

```
create or replace trigger trg_biu_jobas
  before insert or update on job_assignment
  for each row
begin
  if :new.start_date < sysdate then
     raise_application_error(-20001, 'Start date must be after "now"');
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably would have to use a trigger here:

```
CREATE TRIGGER chk_date_today
BEFORE INSERT ON job_assignment
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.start_date < SYSDATE()) THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'start_date must be after now');
   END IF;
END;
```